# Closure of "F ∪ {a}" meaning

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

My question is rather simple:

$F$ being a field, what is the meaning of "the closure of $F \cup \{a\}$ under $+,-,*,÷$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means all numbers you can construct using elements of $F \cup \{a\}$ and operations $+,-,*,\div$.